# Multiple Buttons with a Single Segue

Tags: ios, segue

I have four buttons and one segue. When any of these buttons get touch up inside event, it will load respective images on the destination view controller. For that, I am recognizing buttons through their tag property [each button (0,1,2,3)]. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)Session1Btn:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isSection" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)Session2Btn:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isSection" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)Session3Btn:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isSection" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)Session4Btn:(id)sender {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isSection" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    SectionViewController *sVC=[segue destinationViewController];
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"isSection"])
    {
       // the following line gives an error!
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

       [sVC setSelectedButton:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:tagIndex]];

    }
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Your sender is not a `UIButton` object, but a `SessionViewController` object.

Comment: Could you please elaborate little bit in detail.

Comment: If you search what means your error message, you'll understand my comment. It's not a solution, just pointing the issue. Edit: you put "self" in `sender` parameter, which explain why. Replace it with `sender`

Comment: Use sender:sender in [self performSegue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have written **UIButton UITouchUpInside** event like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isSection" sender:sender];
}
```

Same way for all your buttons.

Now add one variable `UIButton *selectedButton` in **.h file**. and update your button event methods like below:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isSection" sender:sender];
}
```

And now you have `selectedButton` reference, which can be used in other methods. So that,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UIButton *)sender {

    SectionViewController *sVC=[segue destinationViewController];
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"isSection"])
    {
       [sVC setSelectedButton:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: selectedButton.tag]];

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your descriptive answer

Answer (score 0):

## Swift

Create property for the selected button:
`var selectedButton: Int = Int()`

In each IBAction assign `selectedButton` to either 1 or 2 and add `performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)`.

In prepare for segue add the following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if buttonTapped == 1 {
            // what ever happens when first button selected
        } else if buttonTapped == 2 {
            // what ever happens when second button selected
        }
    }
```